# Get divs and theirs siblings div

Tags: jquery

In the code below, how can I get all divs with ".divInner" class and iterate through them, but I don't want to explicit a class? I've just written divs I need to iterate with class".divInner" to clarify my question. Thanks!

```
<div class="divOuter">
    <div class="divInner">
         <div>
              Código
         </div>
         <div>
              Nome
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divInner">
         <div>
         </div>
         <div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('.divOuter > div')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all of them:

```
$(".divOuter > div").find("div").each(function() {

});
```

For each .divInner, individual .each:

```
$(".divOuter > div").each(function() {
   $(this).find("div").each(function() {

   });
});
```

EDIT: Fixed syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply select the children of the outer `div`:

```
// Get all direct children divs of the elements with class divOuter
var divs = $('.divOuter').children('div');
```

You can use a selector like this:

```
// Get all direct children divs of the elements with class divOuter
var divs = $('.divOuter > div');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `.divOuter` class bit you can do this:

```
$(".divOuter").children().each(function(){ });
```

If you don't have that class, you can do this:

```
$("div:first").children().each(function(){ });
```

[Here is an example of the latter](http://jsfiddle.net/sqZ6W/) (warning: 2 alert popups)